# How do I see the name of the runbook running under Az.Automations?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I want to send a notification to discord about the powershell runbook result with webrequest in my runbooks under azure automations.

Since I want to apply it under all runbooks, I want to use the runbook name in the message so that I can see which runbook the notification is coming from, is there a method to pull the runbook name my codes working in?

I tried

```
$runbookName = $MyInvocation.BoundParameters['Name']
```

but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do this for a notification sending automation job, if you need something like this, I would like to tell you how I solved it.

First go to Diagnostic Settings under your automation account and set up a Log Analytics Workspace to record JobLogs and JobStreams data.

Then follow the Alerts-> Create-> Alert rule steps under the Automation Account you selected and create an Alert Rule. I used the following script for this job.

```
AzureDiagnostics  | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION"  | where Category == "JobLogs"  | where ResultType == "Started" or ResultType == "Completed"
```

You can also use this process to get different information with different queries. I am tracking the start and end of runbooks for this particular job. I also created an alert mechanism that sends runbooks that receive errors in a different version and the errors they receive. Thank you to everyone who is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name` variable to get the name of the current runbook.

```
$runbookName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
```

> To send a notification to discord about the PowerShell runbook result with web request in my runbooks:

You can use the `Invoke-WebRequest` PowerShell command with the `Post` method call along with the below script.

```
$runbookName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
$webhookURL = "https://discord.com/" //Modify URL as per your requirement.
$message = "runbook is completed"
$reqbody = @{                                          
   content = $message
} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $webhookURL -Method Post -Body $reqbody -ContentType "application/json"
```

[image]